# MySql / PHP Update Error

Tags: php, mysql

i work on my database, but there is one problem. When I want to edit a row in my database it don´t work.

**Error Message:**

> Fehler im SQL-Kommando: UPDATE lager SET Entnommen='2018-04-10', Zurückgebracht='2018-04-10', Gerätename='PCE-3-4-18', Kürzel='dhh' WHERE id=1

**tabelle-bearbeiten.php**

```
    <?php
    // Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
    require_once "dbconnect.php";

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "load", "x5cy0ik5GCsNpcXS", "liste"); 

   // übergebene Daten zurück in die Datenbank schreiben
    if (isset($_POST['submit_eingabemaske']))   // Submit-Schaltfläche der Eingabemaske wurde betätigt
    {
        // SQL-Kommando: Ändern von Einträgen
        $sql="UPDATE lager SET Entnommen='$_POST[Entnommen]', Zurückgebracht='$_POST[Zurückgebracht]',
        Gerätename='$_POST[Gerätename]', Kürzel='$_POST[Kürzel]' WHERE id=$_POST[nr]";
        // SQL-Kommando ausführen
        mysqli_query($db,$sql) or exit("Fehler im SQL-Kommando: $sql");
    }

    // SQL-Anfrage: Ergebnis ist eine vorhandene Tabelle
    $sql="SELECT * FROM lager";

    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or exit("Fehler im SQL-Kommando: $sql");

    // Tabelle in HTML darstellen
    echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $item)    // jedes Element $item der Zeile $row durchlaufen
            echo "<td>$item</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"eingabemaske.php?id=$row[0]\">bearbeiten</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

**eingabemaske.php**

```
<?php
    // Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
    require_once "dbconnect.php";

    // SQL-Anfrage: Zeile mit der übergebenen Matrikelnummer  wählen
    $sql="SELECT * FROM lager WHERE id=$_GET[id]";

     // Anfrage ausführen
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or exit("Fehler im SQL-Kommando: $sql");


    // Formular darstellen
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tabelle-bearbeiten.php\">\n";
        echo "<br>Eintragnummer: <input type=\"text\" name=\"nr\" readonly value=\"$row[0]\">\n";
        echo "<br>Entnommen: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Entnommen\" value=\"$row[1]\">\n";
        echo "<br>Zurückgebracht: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Zurückgebracht\" value=\"$row[2]\">\n";
         echo "<br>Gerätename: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Gerätename\" value=\"$row[3]\">\n";
          echo "<br>Kürzel: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Kürzel\" value=\"$row[4]\">\n";
        echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_eingabemaske\" value=\"Ändern\">\n";
        echo "</form>\n";
    }

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the full error message. And NEVER EVER use user input without any form of validation/cleaning (bspw: id=$_GET[id]).

Comment: use prepare statements and/or escaping

Comment: I actually doubt very much that this is the error message you receive or that this is the actual sql statement you execute... Variable substitution won't work the way you have implemented it...

Comment: Your sql statement looks good to me tho. Maybe its the Umlaute which sql might have a problem with (not sure, but possible). If you did not find a solution, I can take a closer look when I get home (I´m german too btw)

Comment: One thing; print your full sql query (i.e. using die or exit) and try executing it through cli or phpmyadmin. Then copy the full error message from there.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt If you like you could search for the problem. :)

Comment: @tadman Thanks.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Please show me an example.

Comment: @arkascha How it´s work?

Comment: @Jean-LucaRöder http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Assuming you're not changing your code to OOP - Change `mysqli_query($db,$sql) or exit("Fehler im SQL-Kommando: $sql");` to `mysqli_query($db,$sql) or exit(mysqli_error($db));` This should give you a more specific error.

Comment: Enabling exceptions in `mysqli` is often a lot better than the tired `or die` approach.